Python and Postgresql Broke My Terminal and APT?
I have Ubuntu 24.04 on a VirtualBox VM.
I installed python3, pip and postgresql with seemingly no errors. Then I closed my terminal to restart it and then I could not open it back up.
This is the second time I have experienced this, the other time it bricked my VM and I thought I had foobar'd it.
Now I have done a fresh install and the same problem has occurred. Whenever I try to sudo apt-get update it says the apt is broken. When I do all the general fixes for the apt it does not work.
Seemingly my apt and dpkg are fine and everything looks to be in order.
I don't understand what the problem is. I have spent days of class time on this. Any help or insight on what to do would be appreciated. I still have to install Django at some point as well.

Python3 is an integral part of the Ubuntu system. What exactly did you install?  If some wrong version of python, things can be expected to break.

@ubfan1 I just input the commands in my syllabus:
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install python3.11
and then made it the default version:
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.11 10
Worth noting when I input python3 --version befpre I did the install to see what the current version of python3 was, the command didn't work.

Hey guys I just found an answer that fixed it for me. You have to revert to the python that your Ubuntu version was shipped with. Mine was 3.12
Simply enter these commands (replacing with your own version of python)
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.12 10
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
Then enter sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade to test for any errors and it should be all good
